# How to change the format of the calender in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Select Date:-";
        Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();

    }
```

In The Label it Shows in the format mm-dd-yyyy.
But I want the format in dd-mm-yyyy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Label1.Text = Label1.Text + Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: Assuming OP doesn't want to change the displayed date format in calendar itself, it's the way to go. But I think "mm" should be "MM" (uppercase) in your format string.

Comment: yeah, I'm just going off of his format.  But yeah, I agree.